# Get 1/0 if current column value exist in another table

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, msbi

First of all, I wrote the following Dax expression to get a table with the list of customers who got more than one loan.

```
VAR table_filter =
FILTER (
    SUMMARIZE (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FACT_ACCOUNT;
            FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
            FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
        );
        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER];
        "abc"; COUNTROWS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                FACT_ACCOUNT;
                FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
                FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
            )
        )
    );
    [abc] > 1
)
```

The following picture represent the result of the previous Dax expression table_filter.

[The result of table_filter variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNnJ2.png)

Next, I wrote this expression to get a column with the list of ID_COSTUMER from the previous table

```
VAR column_filter =
SELECTCOLUMNS ( table_filter; "ClientYes"; FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] )
```

Finally, I used this expression to create a calculated column in the FACT_ACCOUNT table, if I found the value of the current ID_COSTUMER in the column_filter I put 1 else 0.

```
RETURN
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( FACT_ACCOUNT );
        FILTER (
            FACT_ACCOUNT;
            FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] = EARLIER ( column_filter )
        )
    ) > 0;
    1;
    0
)
```

The problem is that the result of column_filter is not a column 
I need a solution to return the FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] column from the result of the first filtered table

I got the following error "the first argument of earlier/earliest is not a valid column reference in the earlier row context".

Comment: I think the problem is that SELECTCOLUMNS -function returns a table, not a column. Does it work, if you change the EARLIER-part to this: EARLIER (column_filter[ClientYes]) ?

Comment: Hi @Gigga, thank you for your reply,
I  tried it but I got the following error 
"   cannot find table 'column_filter'  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IsRenewal :=
VAR Filter_Table =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    FACT_ACCOUNT;
                    FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
                    FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
                );
                FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER];
                "abc"; COUNTROWS (
                    SUMMARIZE (
                        FACT_ACCOUNT;
                        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
                        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
                    )
                )
            );
            [abc] > 1
        );
        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
    )
VAR Latest =
    FILTER (
        Filter_Table;
        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] = EARLIER ( FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( Latest ); 0; 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you create the extra table for the sole purpose to identify if the customer has more than 1 entry. If this is the case, an easier solution is to add a column on your FACT-Account table directly:

```
IsDouble = 
var custID = FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
var rowCount = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(FACT_ACCOUNT); 
    FILTER(FACT_ACCOUNT; FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] = custID))
return IF (rowCount > 1; 1; 0)
```

If you still need to do this based on two table, you need to ensure there is a relation between the tables and the same solution holds.

If you do not have a realtion between the tables, you can use the function: LOOKUPVALUE

Comment: I need to use the filter that i create it in the first Dax expression because my fact table contains the progress of the costumers loans by day. So in each day i load the fact table with the same Costumer_id and loan_id, that's why i created the filter on the fact table to get at first the  group of distinct loan and costumer, then, i filtered them by the costumers who got more than one loan.
Otherwise, What i'm searching is how to return the ID_COSTUMER column from the filtred table, so that i could use it in the LOOKUPVALUE.

Comment: Can you please include in your question the tables you are having, the relevant columns and some data. If it difficult to understand from only the text and code.

Comment: Hi @Aldert, In fact, I Finally found a solution for this problem, I got the result that I wanted in the new calculated column. But, the problem now is when i tried to deploy the model i got the following ERROR, "unable to deploy metadata. reason : The syntax for 'Filter_Table' is incorrect".
I posted a new question in stackoverflow and I included it with the result of the expression that i created, you can find more informations in the followinf URL [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226538/unable-to-deploy-metadata-reason-the-syntax-of-filter-table-is-incorrect).

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me to resolve it.