# Unable to deploy metadata. reason : The syntax of 'Filter_Table' is incorrect

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, business-intelligence, msbi

I created the following calculated column.

```
IsRenewal :=
VAR Filter_Table =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    FACT_ACCOUNT;
                    FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
                    FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
                );
                FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER];
                "abc"; COUNTROWS (
                    SUMMARIZE (
                        FACT_ACCOUNT;
                        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
                        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
                    )
                )
            );
            [abc] > 1
        );
        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
    )
VAR Latest =
    FILTER (
        Filter_Table;
        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] = EARLIER ( FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( Latest ); 0; 1 )
```

The following picture represent the result of the previous Dax expression.
[image: The result of the previous Dax expression]

I got the result that I wanted in the new calculated column.
But the problem is when i tried to deploy the model i got the following ERROR,
"unable to deploy metadata. reason : The syntax for 'Filter_Table' is incorrect".

It seems that the problem is in the first variable that i create it.
So I tried to run the result of Filter_Table in SSMS, but, I didn't get any syntax ERROR.

The following capture present the result of Filter_Table in SSMS 
[image: The result of the first variable in SSMS]

So i need help to find why i couldn't deploy my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i could not use a variable in the calculate column,so I resolved it by using the following expression

```
IsRenewal :=
IF (
    ISBLANK (
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE (
                FILTER (
                    SUMMARIZE (
                        SUMMARIZE (
                            FACT_ACCOUNT;
                            FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
                            FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
                        );
                        FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER];
                        "abc"; COUNTROWS (
                            SUMMARIZE (
                                FACT_ACCOUNT;
                                FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_LOAN_INFORMATION];
                                FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
                            )
                        )
                    );
                    [abc] > 1
                );
                FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER]
            );
            FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] = EARLIER ( FACT_ACCOUNT[ID_COSTUMER] )
        )
    );
    0;
    1
)
```